# Specification of a multilevel model in package lme4 in R

Tags: r, lme4

I have a ***pre-post-control*** design (*see picture below*). A control  group (*c*) is pretested (`pre.c`) and post-tested (`pos.c`). Similarly a treatment group (*t*) is prettested (`pre.t`) and post-tested (`pos.t`). So we have two groups (**group factor**) tested at two time points (**time factor**).

Data for this design appears below (in `R` code).

**Question:** I was wondering if my R code below is correctly capturing both factors (i.e., *time* and *group*) and interaction for this design?

Here is my data and what I have tried (with no success):

```
pre.c = rnorm(100)

pos.c = rnorm(100)

pre.t = rnorm(100)

pos.t = rnorm(100, 5)


data = data.frame(subjects = rep(1:200, each = 2), 
              y = c(pre.c, pos.c, pre.t, pos.t), 
              time = rep(0:1, 200), 
              group = rep(c(0, 1), each = 200))

   library(lme4)

   m1 <- lmer(y ~ time + (time | subjects), data = data)         # Gives Error

   m2 <- lmer(y ~ time * group + (time | subjects), data = data) # Gives Error
```

[image]

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear to me `number of observations (=400) <= number of random effects (=400) for term (time | subjects)`

Comment: @Hugh, I'm really unsure if I have specified the model correctly based on the description I have provided in my question above?